# Mono: Change 'unpack' directory with the Mac Installer

Tags: macos, mono, monomac

I created an application in MonoDevelop, the application runs correctly (as far as I know) as I have ran it through MoMA and it is basically a direct port from Windows.

I downgraded MonoDevelop to 2.8 so I can use the 'Create Mac Installer' as mkbundle was failing a lot and nearly no information exists on the internet about the errors it has (mkbundle was being ran on OS X 10.7 to build a OS X application)

So, basically, after the downgrade, I finally got it packaging correctly and creating an installer.  The installer works.  I ran 'installer' in Terminal to test that it works correctly, and it does.

Except for where it is installing.  It is 'unpacking' the .app file to the bin folder of the project.  That has to be a setting somewhere, as I am running the installer from my Dropbox folder which doesn't even contain the project.

My question is: How do I change the directory that the .app file will be deployed to?  (It is going to be a daemon if that matters where I put it, please tell me, as I have never developed for OS X before this.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnecessary.

The packager will look for a pre-existing .app and overwrite it, rather than putting it in /Applications.

The problem is that there will always be a .app file on the developer's machine.  Everything will work, it just won't work correctly on the dev machine.